# A verb that means "to die of a broken heart"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, phrasal-verbs

Is there any one-word verb, a phrasal verb, or an idiom that means "to die of a broken heart" or "to die of grief/sadness"?

Example:

> She went through a lot of adversities and grief in the past five years. She ended up divorcing her husband two years after marriage, and lost her daughter in an accident. Her mother was diagnosed with breast cancer and the doctors had given up on her.
>
> She couldn't tolerate these horrible incidents, and she finally died at the age of 49.

We can describe her death in these ways:

1. She died of a broken heart.
2. She died of grief.
3. She .....  (a verb/idiom)

> (As a matter of fact, this is part of a sad story that happens in the present-day world. One of the characters is a woman who undergoes too many bitter experiences and loss of loved ones. She eventually dies young. People believe that sadness and grieves killed her.)

Comment: Your question received two close-votes because it doesn't have any example sentence or context. The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @rathony I provided some context.

Comment: There is no harm in using a few paragraph breaks. You should have used "doctors have **given** up on her".

Comment: So what is wrong with "die of a broken heart"? It's just too long for you?

Comment: The best I can think of is _pine away_, but that doesn't necessarily imply dying.

Comment: @sumelic For me yes, but maybe not long enough for you.

Comment: Sumelic is really a good person, and his question was a valid one. Allow me to suggest : [*she lost the will to live*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22lost+the+will+to+live%22&tbm=bks), but alas it is made up six words.

Comment: Let me ask you this:  Why do you think fewer words is better?  What is it you're attempting to do?

Comment: @Hot Licks - I'm doing some Persian-English translation. In Persian, the concept is packed in one word. I just wonder if there is a single-word equivalent for it in English. However, it seems I have to make do with the longer phrases or sentences.

Comment: Yes, to my knowledge there is no single word for the concept, at least no modern one.  (There may well be archaic terms, but they would be poorly understood by most readers.)  You would be better off to provide some good examples of desired usage scenarios and solicit suggestions, including clues as to how "poetic" you wish to be, and any "tone" you wish to convey.

Comment: @Hot Licks - This is part of a sad story that happens in the present-day world. One of the characters is a woman who undergoes too many bitter experiences and loss of loved ones. She eventually dies young. People believe that sadness and grieves killed her.

Comment: Don't tell me.  Edit the info into your question.  And provide a few example sentences.

Answer (score 3):

She finally succumbed to the torment / to the heartbreak(s).

**succumb**, [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/succumb)

> to yield to disease, wounds, old age, etc.; die

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
This answer does not answer the question. The question is a request for a verb, verb phrase, or idiom that means "to die of a broken heart".
Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers.
For help writing a good answer, see [answer].

Comment: I added a definition and link to your answer.  If you don't like it, just change it.  Without a definition, your answer would probably have been deleted fairly soon.

Comment: @ab2 good job, the word *succumb* is very appropriate, but it needed a definition, and a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just joined this forum yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

She (just) ***gave up***.

*Give up* - To resign, surrender; to part with (OED)

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/give+up

Comment: @dan 'give up' doesn't include the element 'die'. My target term has to contain two elements: to die, due to the severity of sadness and grief.

Comment: I don't think there's a single word, no; she would have to "die of a broken heart" or "die of grief" or something

Comment: Or maybe : **She gave up the ghost.** Or **She gave up on living/life.**

Comment: Maybe not the best possible answer (though the best I can come up with - in context '*give up*' can signify ***lose the will to live (and die)***.